# How to sync data between something and android app?

Tags: android, database

I don't exactly know how to express this, but, I want to ask, that if I have some simple data, like some XML files, which i want to get automatically added into my app through the means of internet, how can I do that without regularly adding the XML file into the app manually?

Comment: What does "adding into app" mean? Do you want to package the xml files as resources in the apk or do you want them as store them as app data in the device?

Comment: Try to explain little bit more about your application @Dhiryadev

Comment: See. My app is somewhat like Mobogenie, but in my app we download direct APKs. So I wanted to add those Activites all over the not and not manually.

Answer (score 0):

Wish i could comment but you seems beginner like me and your question is very broad...

I would like to explain that your xml contain Views and View Groups. A view is

> A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is responsible for drawing and event handling

and a View group is consist of various view group. 
For example :- textView is View and LinearLayout is View Group which can contain several textView.

You can play around View and View Group from dynamically from java or XML

What you may want to do in your project/app is to load some data through internet and want to put that data in View dynamically.
You can do this :- 1) Create view in XML 2) Download your image through internet by using one of parsing technique (JSOUP, JSON, XML). 3) update that image dynamically. 
A good tutorial of Jsoup is given here

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ha ha its been a long time since I posted this answer. I learned a lot meanwhile and that answer seems to be weird now. Whatever, if you still not able to understand, you are welcome to ask more :)

Comment: It'd be great if you told me from where you learnt, maybe I too can learn from there!

Comment: I learned through internet so there is no specific source. But I will recommend you to decide a good project that you always wanna build then start off from scratch.